# Python/Bash: pass print output of python code to awk

Tags: python, bash

I need help regarding passing the print output of a python code to awk. I have a python code that prints the following rows line by line:

```
548611.17471, 3,  -1.279,  0.146,  9.823, 4,   0.000,  0.001,  0.001, 5,  -3.229, -4.761, -9.029
548611.37441, 3,  -1.288,  0.184,  9.819, 4,   0.000,  0.001,  0.001, 5,  -3.126, -4.674, -8.900
548611.57439, 3,  -1.228,  0.180,  9.869, 4,   0.000,  0.001,  0.001, 5,  -3.093, -4.559, -8.777
548611.77410, 3,  -1.298,  0.153,  9.886, 4,   0.000,  0.001, -0.001, 5,  -3.219, -4.454, -8.622
548611.97418, 3,  -1.334,  0.127,  9.912, 4,  -0.001, -0.000,  0.001, 5,  -3.395, -4.523, -8.542
548612.17385, 3,  -1.257,  0.127,  9.814, 4,   0.000, -0.000,  0.001, 5,  -3.532, -4.750, -8.573
548612.37372, 3,  -1.279,  0.124,  9.902, 4,   0.000, -0.000, -0.001, 5,  -3.651, -4.978, -8.562
548612.57360, 3,  -1.274,  0.156,  9.869, 4,   0.000,  0.001, -0.001, 5,  -3.740, -5.102, -8.444
548612.77347, 3,  -1.271,  0.134,  9.852, 4,   0.000,  0.001, -0.001, 5,  -3.795, -5.063, -8.357
548612.97335, 3,  -1.300,  0.172,  9.792, 4,   0.000, -0.000, -0.001, 5,  -3.884, -4.924, -8.362
548613.17323, 3,  -1.274,  0.168,  9.862, 4,   0.000, -0.000,  0.001, 5,  -3.941, -4.764, -8.410
548613.37310, 3,  -1.300,  0.136,  9.902, 4,   0.000,  0.001, -0.001, 5,  -3.882, -4.627, -8.469
548613.57298, 3,  -1.262,  0.141,  9.878, 4,   0.000, -0.001, -0.001, 5,  -3.750, -4.468, -8.521
548613.77285, 3,  -1.271,  0.160,  9.871, 4,   0.000, -0.000,  0.001, 5,  -3.580, -4.330, -8.560
```

What I did was to pipe the output to awk to print only the first and fifth column:

```
python accel.py | awk -F , '{print $1","$5}'
```

The problem is that it only stays blank (hangs) and does not produce output. The python code and awk works separately but if piped together, nothing happens.

The python code reads from a sensor, converts the input to string then prints out line by line.

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

---

Edit:

Sorry I forgot to put the print line.
I'm reading it from socket then decoding from byte to string:

```
message, address = s.recvfrom(8192)
        msg=message.decode("utf-8")
        print (msg)
```

It's inside a while statement. As long as there is data input, it will continue to print.

Comment: Try use redirection instead of pipe `>`

Comment: Thanks Vinny, I tried that as well, nothing happens.

Comment: @phiv where is your python code printing ? in `std output` or `std err` ?

Comment: @phiv, check your code for errors. The task is simple. The problem is not in unix pipeline or awk - it's in your python code

Comment: Thanks guys, I included the print line of python. The python code outputs properly.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're actually writing out to stderr and awk is trying to read stdout.

What function are you using in your python code to print / output?

Try awking off this python module (and try replacing `stderr` with `stdout`):

```
import sys

for _ in range(40):
  print(5, 6, file=sys.stderr)
```

Comment: Thanks combinatorist. I included the print line.

Comment: Sorry, @phiv, I don't know much about sockets, but maybe someone who does can help.